# How Ubuntu UI is better/easier than Lubuntu?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I am a web developer coming from a Windows environment.

I recently decided to switch to Linux to enjoy better shell scripting and to be able to use certain Linux only tools.

I chose Lubuntu thinking I would trade shiny graphics for more resources and battery life, it turns out there is quite a difference regarding how to configure, what is preinstalled etc.

So here is a small list of issues that I would like to know if I could solve simply by switching to a standard Ubuntu:

- Drag and drop from one monitor to another (either fails or crashes depending on the situation)
- Dynamic monitor plugging in handling (like if I plug a monitor, my PC should automatically switch to dual monitor, no need to reconfigure every time)
- Multiple monitor windows key + arrow handling (it send my windows only to the main screen)
- Better handling of laptop features (keyboard lightning, touch screen, FN keys, most of it does not work or works poorly)
- Better keyboard shortcuts (there is not even a maximize shortcut, I need to re-script everything)

I am loosing a lot of time and productivity solving this and I am aiming for efficiency.

So will using Ubuntu (or just installing Unity) solve this?

Comment: Maybe Xfce (Xubuntu's desktop) is what you're looking for. It's just as fast as Lubuntu's and has lots of features which are not present in LXDE. Also beautiful and highly customizable.

Comment: The dynamic plugging of monitor part will need to have a script for that.   This doesn't depend on the desktop environment you're using or even OS, you'll find out that in either case you need `xrandr` command (which runs behind the scenes ).

Comment: If you like LXDE but need a stable and usable DE, go with XFCE.

Comment: Also， i suggest you change your username, which acts more like advertisement than username.

Comment: I admit that is my intent and I don't intend to go against the website policy, but is it even the case ? (please note that I am also a contributor in other stack exchange website, I am not just a help and advertisment vampire )

Comment: @Fabby FWIW I think this could probably use a little restructuring, but splitting each bullet into its own question would be too much.. (unless of course they are entirely separate issues, which I suspect a few of them are. That can be addressed in an answer however.)

Comment: @Seth: Canned comment removed... Ping me in chat when you remove yours...  **:P**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problems you've listed would be solved by using Unity, especially the shortcuts thing. I've been using both Unity and LXDE for quite some time.

Unity has great built-in shortcuts and a very good way to handle custom shortcuts. I really can't live without them. *For example* you can move through workspaces using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + an arrow. To move a specific window with you to another workspace just add a <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the previous combination.

LXDE (which is the Lubuntu desktop environment) would only be good if your computer is too old and very low on resources. Of course there are solutions for your problems under LXDE but it would be a tedious process. LXDE can get quite time-consuming. You'd fine more people using unity, and therefore you'd find more answers to your troubles and with a better quality.

...you can install Unity on your current ubuntu, but I advise you to do a clean Ubuntu installation (and then install LXDE with it if you want).

*by the way;* I'm assuming that you mean "workspaces" by "multiple monitors".

Answer (score 0):

For easy customisation I would personally recommend Kubuntu (KDE), or perhaps Ubuntu Gnome, but not Unity.

Unity is quite inflexible (though with addons this can be worked around) about how you position your launcher/task manager, and how it displays. This gets more frustrating when you have multiple monitors and want to fine tune how things display. You can easily add a task manager to your second screen, choose if it shows all windows or just windows from that screen. You also have the option of a traditional task manager or an icon only task manager.

All multi monitor features work well. Hotkey customisation is also exceptional in KDE.

You can even customise the buttons on your window decoration. Choosing which corner your close/minimise/maximise button goes, and even adding extra buttons to pin a window to all work spaces, or to leave it always on top.